# How to dealt with authentication flow in react navigation?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-navigation

I was trying hard to implement authentication flow with firebase in my app and after two days. I successfully did it. However I had a spinner (basically ActivityIndicator) that launches while signing in to prevent multi clicks. After implementing the auth flow I have no idea how to set the spinner tp true/false.

The code before auth flow (to get a better idea):

```
handlelogin = async () => { 
    this.setState({showSpinner: true}); 
    const {email, password} = this.state; 
    await auth .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim(), password) 
    .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')) 
    .catch((error) => this.setState({errorMessage: error.message})); this.setState({showSpinner: false}); };
```

After the auth flow:
The Provider:

```
<AuthContext.Provider value={{
 user,
 setUser,
 login: async (email, password) => {
 await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password); },
 }}> {Screens} 
</AuthContext.Provider>
```

**The function:**

```
function handlelogin() { 
    setSpinner(true); 
    login(email, password).catch((error) =>setErrorMessage(error.code)); 
    setSpinner(false); }
```

When I do this I'm getting an error:

> Warning: Can’t perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

I tried passing the setSpinner as an arguement to `login` but I still get the same error

and this is the button that triggers the spinner:

```
      {spinner == true ? (
    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="white" />
  ) : (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={!email.trim() || !password ? styles.disabled : styles.button}
      disabled={!password || !email.trim()}
      onPress={handlelogin}>
      <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontWeight: '500'}}>Sign in</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 10 days of researching, I got to solve this error
In the function i should've called the `setState` in `.catch` such as:

```
async function handlelogin() { 
    setSpinner(true); 
    await login(email, password).catch((error) => {
    setErrorMessage(error.code))
    }
    setSpinner(false); 
}
```

I hope this helps whoever is facing this problem cause it is frustrating.